# Object schemas/models without ORM, DOM or forms

Tags: python, json, validation, serialization, orm

I've used MongoEngine a lot lately. Apart from the MongoDB integration, I like the idea of defining the structures of entities explicitly. Field definitions make code easier to understand. Also, using those definitions, I can validate objects to catch potential bugs or serialize/deserialize them more accurately.

The problem with MongoEngine is that it is designed specifically to work with a storage engine. The same applies for Django and SQLAlchemy models, which also lack list and set types. My question is, then, **is there an object schema/model library for Python that does automated object validation and serialization, but not object-relational mapping or any other fancy stuff**?

Let me give an example.

```
class Wheel(Entity):
    radius = FloatField(1.0)


class Bicycle(Entity):
    front = EntityField(Wheel)
    back = EntityField(Wheel)


class Owner(Entity):
    name = StringField()
    bicycles = ListField(EntityField(Bicycle))


owner = Owner(name='Eser Aygün', bicycles=[])

bmx = Bicycle()
bmx.front = Wheel()
bmx.back = Wheel()

trek = Bicycle()
trek.front = Wheel(1.2)
trek.back = Wheel(1.2)

owner.bicycles.append(bmx)
owner.bicycles.append(trek)

owner.validate()  # checks the structure recursively
```

Given the structure, it is also easy to serialize and deserialize objects. For example, `owner.jsonify()` may return the dictionary

```
{
    'name': 'Eser Aygün',
    'bicycles': [{
        'front': {
            radius: 1.0
        },
        'back': {
            radius: 1.0
        }
    }, {
        'front': {
            radius: 1.2
        },
        'back': {
            radius: 1.2
        }
    }],
}
```

and you can easily convert it back calling `owner.dejsonify(dic)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said earlier in a comment, I've decided to invent my own wheel. I started implementing an open-source Python library, *Entities*, that just does what I wanted. You can check it out from https://github.com/eseraygun/python-entities/.

The library supports recursive and non-recursive collection types (list, set and dict), nested entities and reference fields. It can automatically validate, serialize, deserialize and generate hashable keys for entities of any complexity. (In fact, de/serialization feature is not complete yet.)

This is how you use it:

```
from entities import *

class Account(Entity):
    id = IntegerField(group=PRIMARY)  # this field is in primary key group
    iban = IntegerField(group=SECONDARY)  # this is in secondary key group
    balance = FloatField(default=0.0)

class Name(Entity):
    first_name = StringField(group=SECONDARY)
    last_name = StringField(group=SECONDARY)

class Customer(Entity):
    id = IntegerField(group=PRIMARY)
    name = EntityField(Name, group=SECONDARY)
    accounts = ListField(ReferenceField(Account), default=list)

# Create Account objects.
a_1 = Account(1, 111, 10.0)  # __init__() recognizes positional arguments
a_2 = Account(id=2, iban=222, balance=20.0)  # as well as keyword arguments

# Generate hashable key using primary key.
print a_1.keyify()  # prints '(1,)'

# Generate hashable key using secondary key.
print a_2.keyify(SECONDARY)  # prints '(222,)'

# Create Customer object.
c = Customer(1, Name('eser', 'aygun'))

# Generate hashable key using primary key.
print c.keyify()  # prints '(1,)'

# Generate hashable key using secondary key.
print c.keyify(SECONDARY)  # prints '(('eser', 'aygun'),)'

# Try validating an invalid object.
c.accounts.append(123)
try:
    c.validate()  # fails
except ValidationError:
    print 'accounts list is only for Account objects'

# Try validating a valid object.
c.accounts = [a_1, a_2]
c.validate()  # succeeds
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking, as `python-entities` hasn't been updated for a while, there are some good libraries out there:

- schematics - https://schematics.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- colander - http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/
- voluptuous - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous (more of a validation library)

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing can be achieved with [remoteobjects](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remoteobjects/1.1), which contains a mechanism (called `dataobject`) to allow you to define the structure of an object such that it can be validated and it can be marshalled easily to and from JSON.

It also includes some functionality for building a REST client library that makes HTTP requests, but the use of this part is not required.

The main `remoteobjects` distribution does not come with specific `StringField` or `IntegerField` types, but it's easy enough to implement them. Here's an example `BooleanField` from a codebase I maintain that uses `remoteobjects`:

```
class BooleanField(dataobject.fields.Field):

    def encode(self, value):
        if value is not None and type(value) is not bool:
            raise TypeError("Requires boolean")
        return super(BooleanField, self).encode(value)
```

This can then be used in an object definition:

```
class ThingWithBoolean(dataobject.DataObject):
    my_boolean = BooleanField()
```

And then:

```
thing = ThingWithBoolean.from_dict({"my_boolean":true})
thing.my_boolean = "hello"
return json.dumps(thing.to_dict()) # will fail because my_boolean is not a boolean
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost there! I couldn't find field classes for specific types like String or Integer. Without them, validation wouldn't work. I still hope that somebody might have implemented models for just models' sake.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that `remoteobjects` doesn't have more types built in, but it does have the "tricky" ones like lists, dicts and nested objects, so I found it easy enough to just implement my own primitive type fields. Our validation is quite tolerant anyway, trying to convert strings containing digits into integers and so forth... so customizing the field types yourself can be beneficial.

Comment: I was glad to see the "tricky ones" :) Defining new field types seems easy too. I think it would be better to have a separate `validate()` method for validation. Validating complex objects whenever a new value is assigned may not be a good idea.

Thanks to you and Francis, I am reaching the conclusion that my requirements are rather specific. Maybe I should try to invent my own wheel.

Comment: Having refreshed my memory on `remoteobjects` I found I actually mislead you on when the validation is applied; it actually happens at the point where you call `to_dict` to get a dictionary to serialize, not on each assignment.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the correct point for the error handling. If you're going to roll something yourself I might still suggest that `remoteobjects` provides some good building blocks that you could extend rather than starting from scratch. You can always subclass `DataObject` and `Field` to customize the behavior.

Comment: I see how it works now. I'll give it a shot tomorrow and I'll decide what to do. Thank you!

Comment: I've decided to go with my own library. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`mongopersist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mongopersist/0.8.1), which uses mongo as a persistence layer for Python objects like ZODB. It does not perform schema validation, but it lets you move objects between Mongo and Python transparently.

For validation or other serialization/deserialization scenarios (e.g. forms), consider [`colander`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/). Colander project description:

> Colander is useful as a system for validating and deserializing data obtained via XML, JSON, an HTML form post or any other equally simple data serialization. It runs on Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2. Colander can be used to:
>
> - Define a data schema.
> - Deserialize a data structure composed of strings, mappings, and lists into an arbitrary Python structure after validating the data structure against a data schema.
> - Serialize an arbitrary Python structure to a data structure composed of strings, mappings, and lists.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want persistence though. I don't want to be depended on any storage solution.

Comment: I just saw your update. Colander seems to satisfy my requirements better. However, it also seems to be bulky for regular use. I'm not sure I need that much complexity. I'll consider it. Thanks again!